# Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting Different Cells of Columns based off Dates

Tags: google-sheets, formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a google spreadsheet where I'm creating a simple project timeline and setup columns for the next few months similar to a gantt chart -

I want to setup a formula where I can specify a date range in a cell that instigates highlighting another cell with a color

So for example G2 lists **10/4/2018** so that date is within the range of the column titled **October 1-5, 2018 WEEK 1** so I need help with a formula to then make that cell change to a color

I'll be doing this for every cell under column G to it's appropriate date range up to January 2019

Hopefully that makes sense? any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFTi4.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vpe1RcAwP9u1Uh2dAFxObrnXeFkVpasse90s_McKxa8/edit#gid=1389971739), I've made a separate sheet called "test solution", and I've applied the conditional formatting to the first four columns (H, I, J, K). This is the custom formula I used for the conditional formatting:

```
=AND(G2>=date(2018,10,1), G2<=date(2018,10,5))
```

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Leon!!! yes!!! this is exactly what I was trying to achieve, thank you so much for looking into this - how in the world do you build these formulas? and that makes sense, add the formula to each column based off column G - I was attacking it with the mindset of placing a formula in column G but now I see that wouldn't make sense - thank you!

Comment: You can watch this video for working with custom formulas in conditional formatting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUwkTRfYpBw&t=196s. It comes with a little experience I guess, youtube tutorials are always helpful

Comment: thank you Leon!! I will check it out - I am back into the file and finding one issue so I am sure I am messing up - would you mind taking a look? in the test version under cell G6 I entered the next range of dates but for some reason the cell is filling up on the row 5 instead of 6 -

Comment: Hi Leon, thank you actually I figured out what I was doing wrong, I was putting in the wrong start of the range so I am all set and thank you again! if you could email your email address to paola.goren@swissarmy.com please! I want to send you a thank you gift!

Comment: Hey, I'm glad I could help and that you fixed your issue. I can't accept your gift, but thank you!

Comment: ok thank you! well one more question though? sorry - so of course someone wants to change the setup and now want to see a range from both the submission and release dates to the columns to the right H to AA so is there a formula where each cell will fill from the start of the submission date to the release date so really look like a gantt chart?

Comment: Hey, I've made another "test solution" in your sample spreadsheet. The formula is:


`=OR(AND(F2>=date(2018,10,x), F2<=date(2018,10,y)), AND(G2>=date(2018,10,x), G2<=date(2018,10,y)))`

x being the start date range.

y being the end date range.

The formula basically checks if G2 OR F2 falls within the range. In the case that either of them falls into the range or both does, it will highlight the cell.

Comment: I think that's it!! thank you so so much for this Leon!!

Comment: Hi Leon, I apologize - I think I am messing up the formula's - I wanted to have each cell highlight in the range of dates from each column - would you be able to recheck and see what I'm doing wrong? thank you again

Comment: Hey Paula, it was my error, the formula produces the wrong results. I've updated it in Test Solution and have done it for all the columns up till the end of October.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to include the formula in a new reply so it's easier to see.

```
=OR(AND(F2>=date(2018,10,x), F2<=date(2018,10,y)), AND(ISNUMBER(G2), G2>=date(2018,10,x)))
```

x is the start date range

y is the end date range

Remember to change the month as well.

So the formula checks for two conditions. If either is true, then the cell turns pink. The first checks if the submission date (F2) falls within the range of that week. The second checks if the release date (G2) comes after the start date of the range of the week.

The previous formula only checked if G2 or F2 was within the range of that column. Meaning that if you had a project that spans 3 weeks, the 1st week would be pink because G2 falls within the range, and the 3rd week would be pink because F2 falls within the range. But the 2nd week will remain white because neither 1/10/2018 or 22/10/2018 falls within the range of 8/10/2018 - 12/10/2018.

Comment: THANK YOU so so much! this worked perfectly - and thank you for the explanation so I could understand

Answer (score -1):

Could you link your sample spreadsheet?

Comment: hi, thank you for responding 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vpe1RcAwP9u1Uh2dAFxObrnXeFkVpasse90s_McKxa8/edit?usp=sharing